# "each element in group" in pug does not show any value

Tags: json, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug, each

I'm trying to populate a dynamic row/col (formerly known as tables) in pug from a JSON object provided with res.render in node.js.

My problem is, that simple values are displayed with ease, but more complex operations like the row/col definition for a dynamic number of elements (here it happens to be media files for a specific audiobook) is not populated.

Here is the snippet with the each... block from my template file:

```
div.form-group
  div.row
    div.col-2
      label(for='varMediaTitle') Titel:
    div.col
      input#MediaTitle.form-control(type='text', placeholder=varMediaTitle, name='varMediaTitle', required)
div.form-group
  div.row
    div.col-4
      label(for='MediaFileName') Audio Dateien:
  div.row
    div.col-1 Nr
    div.col-5 Name
    div.col-2 Groesse
  each mediaFile in varMediaFiles
    div.row
      each itemM in mediaFile
        div.col-1
          p #{itemM.part}
        div.col-5
          p #{itemM.name}
        div.col-2
        p #{itemM.size}
  div.row
    div.col
      input#MediaFileName.form-control(type='file', name='MediaFileName', required)
```

As said, simple elements in the template, such as a media title which I simply show in an input field (without iteration), are correctly displayed, but the block with each mediaFile in varMediaFiles is not displaying any content.

Interestingly, when inspecting the resulting html, I can see the correct number of rows. That is, the number of created rows correspond to the number of elements in my json file.

[image: html inspection in chrome]

Here you can see my call to the form from my node.js function:

```
res.render('tags', {
                title: 'RFID Tag Datenseite',
                headline: 'RFID Tag Daten',
                subheadline: 'Tag ' + obj.TagId + ' - ' + obj.MediaTitle,
                varTagId: obj.TagId,
                varTagPreTag: obj.TagPreTag,
                varTagChecksum: obj.TagChecksum,
                varTagRawData: obj.TagRawData,
                varMediaTitle: obj.MediaTitle,
                varMediaType: obj.MediaType,
                varMediaGenre: obj.MediaGenre,
                varMediaDescription: obj.MediaDescription,
                varMediaFiles: obj.MediaFileName,
                varMediaPictures: obj.MediaPicture
            });
```

And this is the structure of the json file (it is an actual file read in from filesystem), from which the values are passed to the form:

```
{
  "TagChecksum": "0x97",
  "TagId": "759C71",
  "TagPreTag": "0xf00",
  "TagRawData": "0F00759C7197",
  "MediaTitle": "The 6th book",
  "MediaType": "Audiobook",
  "MediaGenre": "UNDEFINED",
  "MediaDescription": "Beschreibung",
  "MediaFileName": [{"part": "1", "name": "1st-file.mp3", "size": "6M"}, {"part": "2", "name": "2nd-file.mp3", "size": "8M"}],
  "MediaPicture": [{"pic": "1", "name": "1st-pic.jpg"}, {"pic": "2", "name": "2nd-pic.jpg"}, {"pic": "3", "name": "3rd-pic.jpg"}]
}
```

Any idea, why simple values without iteration work, but an iteration over a json array does not???

My first thought was that it is because it's and array within a json structure and that I might have an issue with the format of the json file. But in that case, I can't understand, why the each... block correctly creates the number of rows.

There is, however, one additional glitch. After inspecting the html output (see attached picture) I came to notice, that the iteration actually creates the correct number of rows (here 2 for the media files), but far too many cols for each row. It looks like it puts all cols of all rows in all rows - very strange.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Best regards and many many thanks,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out and thought, since there was no answer at all to this question but quite a few views, it might just be worth to post the solution, so other newbies like me can find it.

The solution was actually quite simple.

The second iteration (that is the each itemM ... block from my question above) was completely nonsense and I simply got rid of it. Instead of iterating through the elements within one of the json array structures, I referenced it directly.

I also exchanged 'each' as a statement with 'for', but I'm not sure if this is necessary.

In the end, my each...block (which did not work):

```
  each mediaFile in varMediaFiles
    div.row
      each itemM in mediaFile
        div.col-1
          p #{itemM.part}
        div.col-5
          p #{itemM.name}
        div.col-2
        p #{itemM.size}
```

became this for...block (which works):

```
    for mediaFile in varMediaFiles
      div.row
        div.col-1
          p #{mediaFile.part}
        div.col-5
          p #{mediaFile.name}
        div.col-2
          p #{mediaFile.size}
```

The reason for this is pretty clear, once I figured it out. I do not have a nested array - in which case a nested each or for loop would probably have done the trick. I have a json structure with an array of json elements.

```
[{"part": "1", "name": "1st-file.mp3", "size": "6M"}, {"part": "2", "name": "2nd-file.mp3", "size": "8M"}],
```

Each element of this array is again a json structure. Since it is a json structure I can simply reference the part of the json element by name, while iterating through the array elements.

Sometimes it's actually simpler then one might think.

Happy coding to all,

Christian